# Use kubectl to delete a node that has running pods on it

Tags: kubernetes

We are using Heat + Kubernetes (V0.19) to manage our apps. When do rolling update, sometimes container staring will always fail on a node but kubelet on the node will always retry but always fail. So the updating will hang there which is not the behavior we expected.

I found that using "kubectl delete node" to remove the node can avoid pods scheduled to that node. But in our env, the node to be deleted may have running pods on it.

So my question is:
After using "kubectl delete node" to remove the node, will the pods on that node still worked correctly ?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to cancel the rolling update, remove the failed pods and try again later, I have found that it is best to stop the update loop with `CTRL+c` and then delete the replication controller corresponding to the new app that is failing.

```
    ^C
    kubectl delete replicationcontrollers your-app-v1.2.3
```

Comment: We do not want to cancel the update. We just want to let the upgrade work correctly.

Comment: If you wish to let the update run and instead mark the node as dead I believe there is a window of time (minutes) before kubernetes reschedules the pods existing on that node. I cant say for sure since I don't run the same version as you. So assuming deleting the node immediately relocates the update there is a window of time where catastrophe is avoided.

In the long run this is not a viable solution I do not recommend this as a common practice so proceed at your own risk.